Is there anyway of preserve data while switching to another tab inside an app?
I have an app where I have 4 sections, and each section does different things. For example, the user needs to select what language they need to translate from and to through a drop down menu. However, whenever I switch to another section, and then go back, all the data that the user has inputted has disappeared. Is there a way to prevent this?
public void selectTranslateTo() {
    PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(getApplicationContext(), selectTranslateTo);

    // Inflating popup menu from popup_menu.xml file
    popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.select_language, popupMenu.getMenu());
    popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
            // Toast message on menu item clicked
            selectTranslateTo.setText(menuItem.getTitle());
            translateToButton = menuItem.getTitle().toString();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You Clicked " + menuItem.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
    });
    // Showing the popup menu
    popupMenu.show();
}

public void selectTranslateFrom() {
    PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(getApplicationContext(), selectTranslateFrom);

    // Inflating popup menu from popup_menu.xml file
    popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.select_language, popupMenu.getMenu());
    popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
            // Toast message on menu item clicked
            selectTranslateFrom.setText(menuItem.getTitle());
            translateFromButton = menuItem.getTitle().toString();


            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You Clicked " + menuItem.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
    });
    // Showing the popup menu
    popupMenu.show();

}

I also have an image URI that I want to save, is there a way to do this?
If there is anything else needed please let me know.
This is the code that switches pages
void toHome() {
        Intent i = new Intent(ImageTranslateActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
        finish();
    }

    void toText() {
        startActivity(new Intent(ImageTranslateActivity.this, TextTranslateActivity.class));
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
        finish();
    }

    void toVoice() {
        startActivity(new Intent(ImageTranslateActivity.this, VoiceTranslateActivity.class));
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
        finish();
    }

    void toDownload() {
        startActivity(new Intent(ImageTranslateActivity.this,  DownloadLanguageTranslatePackages.class));
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
        finish();
    }


You can use a ViewModel to help preserve the value.
